# How to perform cartesian joins within groups on large RDD's most efficiently?

Tags: memory, apache-spark, rdd

I have 2 RDD's (one with 11 million records and other with 5000 records), in the format (K, V)...(Kn, Vn). There are many values associated with a key and I need to do a cartesian product for each key. I have tried using joins and cross joins with filters or conditions but they take 2.5 hours. I have a 8 node, 4 core and 32 GB RAM per node cluster so expected much better performance!

Comment: How are both `RDD` partitioned?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Java, there is a method called cartesian in JavaPairRDD class.

```
rdd1.cartesian(rdd2);
```

I hope the same method should be available in scala as well.

Also, you can try to broadcast the second rdd and try some join.